# Make table wider then container

Tags: html, css

I have a table that sits inside a container.

I want the table to be 20px wider than the container on both sides, and I can't get it working.

I tried changing `margin: 0 auto;` on the table element to `margin: 0 -40px;` so that it would overhang by 20px on each side of the container, but that just shifts the entire table to the left.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 1;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

table * {
  position: relative;
}

table td,
table th {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

table thead tr {
  height: 60px;
  background: #36304a;
}

table tbody tr {
  height: 50px;
}

table tbody tr:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

table td,
table th {
  text-align: left;
}

table td.l,
table th.l {
  text-align: right;
}

table td.c,
table th.c {
  text-align: center;
}

table td.r,
table th.r {
  text-align: center;
}

.header th {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

tbody tr {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #808080;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column {
  width: 160px;
}

.column:first-child {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.column:last-child {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th class="column">1</th>
        <th class="column">2</th>
        <th class="column">3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="column">mnbvbmvn</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">28761528</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">Some text here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="column">adsfasdf</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">12341234</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">blah blah blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="column">ajgsgdsdjha</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">85765</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">some other text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the minimum width `min-width: 100%;` instead of `width` and also set a negative margin as desired, to have the table horizontally centered.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 1;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -20px;
}

table * {
  position: relative;
}

table td,
table th {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

table thead tr {
  height: 60px;
  background: #36304a;
}

table tbody tr {
  height: 50px;
}

table tbody tr:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

table td,
table th {
  text-align: left;
}

table td.l,
table th.l {
  text-align: right;
}

table td.c,
table th.c {
  text-align: center;
}

table td.r,
table th.r {
  text-align: center;
}

.header th {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

tbody tr {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #808080;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column {
  width: 160px;
}

.column:first-child {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.column:last-child {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th class="column">1</th>
        <th class="column">2</th>
        <th class="column">3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="column">mnbvbmvn</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">28761528</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">Some text here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="column">adsfasdf</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">12341234</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">blah blah blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="column">ajgsgdsdjha</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">85765</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">some other text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Many similar answers, but gave it to you because this was the simplest (no calc required) and also had a full example. Cheers.

Comment: Ok slight problem with a real world implementation. If the table has many columns it will not sit in the center. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/acb6hsjo/4/. Any idea how to remedy?

Comment: Kind of, but this is getting a bit silly: https://jsfiddle.net/acb6hsjo/13/ this set's the container to `display: flex` and `flex-flow: column nowrap;`. This will actually center the content, but as you see maybe cuts of content from the left and right. It depends on your use case how to toggle these challenges.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using the css calc function like this as no one wants to set negative margins and padding this is the best way in my opinion.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 1;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:calc (100% + 40px) ;
  margin: 0 auto;
   
  position: absolute;
  left:-20px;
}

table * {
  position: relative;
}

table td,
table th {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

table thead tr {
  height: 60px;
  background: #36304a;
}

table tbody tr {
  height: 50px;
}

table tbody tr:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

table td,
table th {
  text-align: left;
}

table td.l,
table th.l {
  text-align: right;
}

table td.c,
table th.c {
  text-align: center;
}

table td.r,
table th.r {
  text-align: center;
}

.header th {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

tbody tr {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #808080;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column {
  width: 160px;
}

.column:first-child {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.column:last-child {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th class="column">1</th>
        <th class="column">2</th>
        <th class="column">3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="column">mnbvbmvn</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">28761528</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">Some text here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="column">adsfasdf</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">12341234</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">blah blah blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="column">ajgsgdsdjha</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">85765</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">some other text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

change table `width` and `margin` as following.

```
table {
  border-spacing: 1;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc(100% + 40px);
  margin: 0 -20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: you should always add an explanation to your answers - never just answer

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your table css

```
table {
border-spacing: 1;
border-collapse: collapse;
background: white;
border-radius: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
width: calc(100% + 40px);/* to give it extra width on both sides */
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
margin-left: -20px;/* to push the table to left */
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
border-spacing: 1;
border-collapse: collapse;
background: white;
border-radius: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
width: calc(100% + 40px);
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
margin-left: -20px;
}

table * {
  position: relative;
}

table td,
table th {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

table thead tr {
  height: 60px;
  background: #36304a;
}

table tbody tr {
  height: 50px;
}

table tbody tr:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

table td,
table th {
  text-align: left;
}

table td.l,
table th.l {
  text-align: right;
}

table td.c,
table th.c {
  text-align: center;
}

table td.r,
table th.r {
  text-align: center;
}

.header th {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

tbody tr {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #808080;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: unset;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column {
  width: 160px;
}

.column:first-child {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.column:last-child {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th class="column">1</th>
        <th class="column">2</th>
        <th class="column">3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="column">mnbvbmvn</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">28761528</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">Some text here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="column">adsfasdf</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">12341234</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">blah blah blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="column">ajgsgdsdjha</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">85765</td>
        <td class="column" data-title="Points">some other text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Negative value for width is meaningless. So, use negative value for margin. And remove the `width: 100%` so the table could be bigger than its parent.

```
margin: 0 -20px;
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I was using the negative value on the margin and it just shifts the table to the left. I have fixed the question now.

Comment: I added to the answer, remove the `width: 100%`.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the width of the table to be 100% plus the 20 pixels on each side

```
width: calc(100% + 40px);
```

you can move outside of the bounds of the container by using a negative margin

```
margin: 0 -20px;
```

This will both center your table and grow it larger than your container.